# Why doesn't html unescape work here?

Tags: python, html, escaping

This is how I am getting the data:

```
page = requests.get('some website')
data = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.content,"lxml")
```

I'm using this to do the unescaping:

```
from xml.sax.saxutils import unescape
html_escape_table = { '"':"&quot;", "'":"&apos;"}
html_unescape_table = {v:k for k,v in html_escape_table.items()}

def html_unescape(text):
    return unescape(text,html_unescape_table)
```

When I try to call unescape on any part of `data` (which I believe is a string), it doesn't do the unescaping as it should. Instead, it just returns the same string that I called the function with (ex. `\u00e8`).

However when I try to call `html_unescape()` passing in a string that I physically typed (Ex. `html_unescape('\u00e8')`, it works.

Why doesn't it work when I pass in a piece of string from the data I got with BeautifulSoup?

Comment: In your `html_unescape` function put a `print(type(text))` before the `return` -- what does it say?

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! It prints `<class 'str'>`

Comment: Hmm, standard Python would have that be `<type 'str'>` -- that must be a custom class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard Python would print `<type 'str'>` not `<class 'str'>` -- you must have received a custom `str` class.  You'll need to track down where that came from (`requests`?  `BeautifulSoup`?) and see what operations it supports.

Comment: It seems to return `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'` :/

Comment: @DianaChang: Looks like a custom class -- you'll need to track down where it came from and see what operations it supports.